# Vote How to view Cypher queries back for a database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have used Neo4J ETL tool and create a Neo4J database from Postgres SQL and this looks perfect. I can see all nodes, relationships, data, etc.

Now I want to see all the database file, the Cypher queries for all node and relationship creation along with different constraint applied to this database.

How can I view this? I can see database folder is empty for Neo4J home,

`C:\Users\I\.Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-9cf178b6-f37f-4139-8b80-dadf0fa03866\data\databases`

2nd question, can I generates graphql schema from the Cypher script using any tool or some mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below codes can help you to get meta-data and schema

```
// Show meta-graph
CALL db.schema.visualization()

// List node labels
CALL db.labels()

// List relationship types
CALL db.relationshipTypes()
```